# My choice of fieldname for CakePHP's form helper is not working properly, why?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating an AJAX form. The problem is when I'm trying to create a input form with formhelper, my input's name attribute is not correctly renedered in the view. Here's my code:

```
$form->input('MainAttribute.'.$i.'.SubAttribute.'.$j.'.score', array('label' => '', 'options' => $scores));
```

I created it that way because I want SubAttribute to be inside MainAttribute. When I inspect the HTML, the name attribute of the form is cutted of like:

```
name="data[SuperMainAttribute]"
```

How can I specify the name attribute to the one that I'm planning on doing?
(e.g. data[MainAttribute][0][SubAttribute][0][score])

Edit:

Here are my model relationships:

Control hasMany MainAttribute

MainAttribute hasMany SubAttribute

The ctp is in a view of the Control Controller

Comment: If you have your models configured with the correct relationships, Cake will do that for you. There is no need to specify the array dimensions. Try it without and pr($this->data) in your controller.

Comment: whoa so I can do saveAll($this->data) without having to re-organize the structure of $this->data?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the model relationships you've defined? This is important because `Model::saveAll()` _doesn't_ save HABTM-associated model data.

Comment: Well I was making the assumption that your MainAttribute is a model associated with your SubAttribute model.

Comment: David, yes they're associated

Comment: So you're trying to save a `Control`, its associated `MainAttributes`, and _their_ associated `SubAttributes`? Unfortunately, there's no way to get all three models' data saved in a single `saveAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, *almost* anytime you call `FormHelper::input`, the first parameter will appear in one of the following formats:

- for the primary model, or `hasOne` and `belongsTo` associations: `$form->input('Model.field')`
- for `hasMany` associations: `$form->input("Model.{$n}.field")`
- for `hasAndBelongsToMany` associations: `$form->input("Model.Model.{$n}.field")`

(In these cases, `$n` is an iterator (`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`, etc.), allowing you to add multiple records to `hasMany`- and `hasAndBelongsToMany`-associated models.)

Your specific case is tricky, because you want to save a `Control` record, and all of its `MainAttribute` records, and all of each `MainAttribute`'s `SubAttribute` records. This isn't possible without some data manipulation in the controller. The way I'd probably tackle this problem is the following.

In the view:

```
echo $form->create('Control', array('action'=>'add'));

echo $form->input('Control.field_name');

$iLimit = 4;
$jLimit = 2;
for ($k=$i=0;$i<$iLimit;$i++) {

    echo $form->input("MainAttribute.{$i}.field_name");

    for ($j=0;$j<$jLimit;$j++) {
        echo $form->input("SubAttribute.{$k}.ixMainAttribute", array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$i));
        echo $form->input("SubAttribute.{$k}.field_name");
        $k++;
    }
}

echo $form->end('Submit');
```

In `ControlsController`:

```
function add()
{
    if (! empty($this->data)) {

        // Perform data validation separately...

        if ( $this->Control->save( $this->data['Control'], false )) {

            foreach ( $this->data['MainAttribute'] as $k => $_data ) {

                $_subAttributes = Set::extract("/SubAttribute[ixMainAttribute={$k}]", $this->data);

                $insert = array(
                    'MainAttribute' => am( $_data, array('control_id' => $this->Control->id)),
                    'SubAttribute'  => $_subAttributes
                );

                $this->Control->MainAttribute->saveAll($insert, array('validate'=>false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTH.